# How to setup oracle instant client in node alpine (docker)?

Tags: node.js, docker, alpine-linux, oracleclient

I am trying to setup oracle instant client in docker node alpine image. I have tried all the techniques mentioned in the oracle official blog plus the official website.

```
FROM node:14.17-alpine
WORKDIR /opt/oracle

RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    rm -f instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip && \
    apk add libaio libnsl && \
    cd instantclient* && \
    rm -f *jdbc* *occi* *mysql* *jar uidrvci genezi adrci && \
    # echo /opt/oracle/instantclient* > /etc/ld.so.conf.d/oracle-instantclient.conf && \
    # ldconfig
# RUN wget https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/213000/instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.3.0.0.0.zip
# #unzip instant client
# RUN unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.3.0.0.0.zip
# RUN rm instantclient-basic-linux.x64-21.3.0.0.0.zip
# RUN mv instantclient_21_3 /opt/oracle
# RUN apk add libaio libnsl
# ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/instantclient_21_3:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/opt/oracle/${version}/client64/lib:$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

I have tried both approaches the ld_library_path plus the ld_config way, tried with multiple different versions of the instant client, none of them worked.

I get the following error

```
{

      "type": "Error",

      "message": "DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: \"Error loading shared library **libclntsh.so**: Exec format error\". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help\nNode-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html\nYou must have 64-bit Oracle Client libraries configured with ldconfig, or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.\nIf you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from \nhttps://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html\n",

      "stack":

          Error: DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "Error loading shared library libclntsh.so: Exec format error". See https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html for help

          Node-oracledb installation instructions: https://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/INSTALL.html

          You must have 64-bit Oracle Client libraries configured with ldconfig, or in LD_LIBRARY_PATH.

          If you do not have Oracle Database on this computer, then install the Instant Client Basic or Basic Light package from 

          https://www.oracle.com/database/technologies/instant-client/linux-x86-64-downloads.html

          

              at OracleDb.getConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/oracledb/lib/oracledb.js:273:25)

              at OracleDb.getConnection (/usr/src/app/node_modules/oracledb/lib/util.js:178:19)

              at connectOracle (/usr/src/app/server/services/service1/dist/lib/index.js:20:70)

              at startServer (/usr/src/app/server/services/service1/dist/lib/index.js:46:57)

              at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/src/app/server/services/service1/dist/lib/index.js:75:5)

              at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:14)

              at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1101:10)

              at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32)

              at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12)

              at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:76:12)

              at internal/main/run_main_module.js:17:47

      "errorNum": 0,

      "offset": 0

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

This works for me:

```
RUN apk --no-cache add libaio libnsl libc6-compat curl && \
    cd /tmp && \
    curl -o instantclient-basiclite.zip https://download.oracle.com/otn_software/linux/instantclient/instantclient-basiclite-linuxx64.zip -SL && \
    unzip instantclient-basiclite.zip && \
    mv instantclient*/ /usr/lib/instantclient && \
    rm instantclient-basiclite.zip && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libclntsh.so.19.1 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libocci.so.19.1 /usr/lib/libocci.so && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libociicus.so /usr/lib/libociicus.so && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libnnz19.so /usr/lib/libnnz19.so && \
    ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.2 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1 && \
    ln -s /lib/libc.so.6 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 && \
    ln -s /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2

ENV ORACLE_BASE /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV TNS_ADMIN /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/instantclient
RUN apk add dumb-init
ENV NODE_ENV production
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY --chown=node:node . /usr/src/app
RUN npm ci --only=production
RUN npm cache clean --force
EXPOSE 3002
CMD ["node", "./src/app.js" ]
```

Comment: You can simplify this a bit: It's best not to set ORACLE_HOME (or ORACLE_BASE) with Instant Client. The first one can have side effects. Both variables are for full Oracle DB installations. Also, there is no point setting TNS_ADMIN: the location you use is already the default.  My post [here](https://blogs.oracle.com/opal/post/part-1-docker-for-oracle-database-applications-in-nodejs-and-python) shows some files you can remove from Instant Client to save a few more bytes.  (For the record, if anyone is using Python on Alpine, try python-oracledb which doesn't need Instant Client)

Comment: In Alpine docker container run apk command from above, then

export ORACLE_BASE='/usr/lib/instantclient'                                        

export LD_LIBRARY_PATH='/usr/lib/instantclient'                                      

export TNS_ADMIN='/usr/lib/instantclient'                                           

export ORACLE_HOME='/usr/lib/instantclient'

Answer (score 1):

I'm using Oracle `instantclient_19_22` and got the following error when starting the Docker container:

> `DPI-1047: Cannot locate a 64-bit Oracle Client library: "Error loading shared library libnsl.so.1: No such file or directory (needed by /opt/oracle/instantclient/libclntsh.so)".`

I borrowed 3 lines from [Ravil's answer](/a/76372516). That fixed 3 missing shared library errors for me (`libnsl.so.1`, `libresolv.so.2`, and `ld-linux-x86-64.so.2`).

```
RUN ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.3 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1 && \
    ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 && \
    ln -s /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2
```

I only need those 3 lines. Everything seems working fine.

Comment: I'm guessing that the other answer got downvoted because it was more of a "config dump" without any explanation or context.  While you are right that it would normally be better as a comment, I actually consider this a better answer since it zeros in on the actual solution.  More explanation on *why* it fixes the problem would be even better, but it's a good answer as it stands.  And, if you desire, you now have the reputation needed in order to upvote the original answer (as well as the question).

Answer (score -1):

For those who found the post in google. Fresh solution to the issue. Tested sqplus and zabbix oracle data gathering, both work fine. You may want to use clean alpine linux image

```
FROM zabbix/zabbix-agent2:6.4.2-alpine

USER root

WORKDIR /home

ENV ORACLE_BASE /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV LD_LIBRARY_PATH /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV TNS_ADMIN /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV ORACLE_HOME /usr/lib/instantclient
ENV PATH /usr/lib/instantclient:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin

ADD tnsnames.ora /home
ADD instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /home
ADD instantclient-odbc-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0-2.zip /home
ADD instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip /home

RUN apk add --no-cache libaio libnsl unixodbc-dev && \
unzip instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip && \
unzip instantclient-odbc-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0-2.zip && \
unzip instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip && \
mv instantclient*/ /usr/lib/instantclient && \
rm instantclient-basic-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip && \
rm instantclient-odbc-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0-2.zip && \
rm instantclient-sqlplus-linux.x64-12.2.0.1.0.zip && \
ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /usr/lib/instantclient/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 && \
ln -s /usr/lib/libaio.so.1 /usr/lib/instantclient/libaio.so.1 && \
ln -s /usr/lib/libgcc_s.so.1 /usr/lib/instantclient/libgcc_s.so.1 && \
ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libclntsh.so.12.1 /usr/lib/libclntsh.so && \
ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libocci.so.12.1 /usr/lib/libocci.so && \
ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libociicus.so /usr/lib/libociicus.so && \
ln -s /usr/lib/instantclient/libnnz12.so /usr/lib/libnnz12.so && \
ln -s /usr/lib/libnsl.so.3 /usr/lib/libnsl.so.1 && \
ln -s /lib/libc.musl-x86_64.so.1 /usr/lib/libresolv.so.2 && \
ln -s /lib/ld-musl-x86_64.so.1 /usr/lib/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 && \
mkdir -p $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin && \
mv /home/tnsnames.ora $ORACLE_HOME/network/admin
```